# Hybris E&M environment variable in linux

Tags: linux, sap-commerce-cloud

I need to set "H&M" environment variable in linux for Hybris platform. I am aware of "export" command. How to escape ampersand symbol in linux environment variable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think this is possible.
When I escape it like this:

```
export H\&M=myValue
```

I get:

```
-bash: export: `H&M=myValue': not a valid identifier
```

Regarding the hybris part of the question: For what is this variable needed?

Comment: Documentation says only this:
 `{E&M_HOME} refers to the hybris-ems directory that holds the following folders: binary, documentation, sample-configs, and source.`

So I belive this variable helps to configure tutorial part, "hello world" example. I have solved this problem by skipping this point in documentation.

Comment: Hi @RadosławOsiński.. I looked it up in the hybris wiki (for the ones with wiki access it is e.g. https://wiki.hybris.com/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=239379021#Entitlement&MeteringService-InstallationGuide-Prerequisites, right above that anchor). They refer to this {E&M_HOME}  only as a variable within the documentation page, so this is not meant to be an actual environment variable. Maybe this is misleading sometimes as it does look a lot like an actual "code" variable, while it is only a "documentation" bit.